# tns run android –bundle fails with element not found

Tags: android, webpack, bundle, nativescript, nativescript-cli

My application runs fine when I run using tns run android but when I use **tns run android --bundle** then it gives me following exception.

> ‘nativescript-ui-sidedrawer’ not found for element 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer:RadSideDrawer

I see following mentioned in my bundle-config.js.

```
global.registerModule("nativescript-ui-sidedrawer",
    () => require("../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer"));
```

I have tried to add/remove android platform and plugin to and from the project. I also tried giving different paths but no luck.

```
global.registerModule("nativescript-ui-sidedrawer",
    () => require("../nativescript-ui-sidedrawer"));

global.registerModule("nativescript-ui-sidedrawer",
    () => require("./nativescript-ui-sidedrawer"));
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file (based on the code I am guessing that you are using NativeScript Core and not an Angular based project) add the drawer namespace as explained in the documentation section [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/getting-started).

```
<Page xmlns:nsDrawer="nativescript-ui-sidedrawer>
<!-- page content follows here-->
</Page>
```

and then use it in the XML as follows:

```
<!-- page content follows here-->
<nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer">
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. This is how I am using it. I can side drawer working fine. It is just when I run the application using tns run android --bundle I get that issue.

Comment: For custom components like the UI plugins you will need to register them manually for the Wwebpack as done here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/release/sdk/app/bundle-config.ts#L11-L18

Comment: Create the bundle-config.js file and add register the plugin via registerModule (you can copy-paste the file content from the link above)

Comment: I tried that as well but got again following error: com.package.app/app/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer' not found for element 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer:RadSi
deDrawer'. Failed to find module: "/data/data/com.package.app/files/app/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer".